# Updating a table field with variables

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me please...I am running the following query but it keeps failing.

I want to replace the S with RS in the field (there are other variables in the same field) but only want to replace the S variables to RS

```
update
 MDSCLMDTL
set
 STATUS_CODE= 'rs' where STATUS_CODE ='s'
```

Comment: Have a look at [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Replace` Function

```
update
 MDSCLMDTL
set
 STATUS_CODE= Replace(STATUS_CODE,'s','rs')
 where charindex('s',STATUS_CODE)> 0 -- To filter the rows which doesnot have 's' character
```